# Spring - Change schema connection for persistent_logins

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, jpa

I am working on a Spring Boot web application and I am implementing the "Remember me" function.

I defined in my Web Security Configuration this:

```
http.authorizeRequests().and()
                    .rememberMe().tokenRepository(this.persistentTokenRepository())
                    .tokenValiditySeconds(1 * 24 * 60 * 60); // 24h
```

and

```
@Bean
        public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
            JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl db = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
            db.setDataSource(dataSource);
            return db;
        }
```

The problem is that when I flag the option on the html page, Spring try to add a token in the default schema of my database -> "public".

Is there any way to change the default schema for that option? Everything else is linked correctly on the right schema through this property:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=another_schema_name
```

I tried to make a personal implement of the class JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl but I can't find a way to change the schema. I looked it up online but I didn't find nothing..

Thank you

Regards,
Mohamad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may initialize differently your dataSource variable what you use in your PersistentTokenRepository bean. Most data sources support schema setting. For instance Spring's org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource :

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource getDataSource() {
  DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
  // ... tipicly set username, password, driver class name, jdbc Url
  dataSource.setSchema(schema);
  return dataSource;
}
```

You could control the schema through the mentioned property: (spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema)

```
@Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema}")
private String schema;
```